# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNPermissionHandlerLocationWhenInUse", referenced bjc-class-ref in libRNPermissions.a(RNPermissions.o)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Getting the below error while running the iOS app in the cloud machine. But in local it works fine and able to archive the ipa.

```
.../_appcircle_temp/appcircle_export_archive/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/ShopDrop.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/App normal arm64

(1 failure)

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNPermissionHandlerLocationWhenInUse", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in libRNPermissions.a(RNPermissions.o)
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason you are seeing this error is, either you forgot to run `pod install` or your podfile is missing similar like

```
pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
```

but you have similar line defined in `info.plist`

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your location is required to match bikes best for you.</string>
```

---

make sure both items above are declared in configurations. If you do not need the permission, remove the declarations.

### Still not working?

If still not working then try clearing xcode cache. Delete folders in
  `/Users/{YOUR_USERNAME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
and try again.

```
rm ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```